# Unable to perform php in command line

Tags: php, arrays, nested

I am new to php scripting and been following a tutorial video. I'm getting an error on trying to output an array from php via command line, this is the code named as array1.php:

```
<?
# Canada, USA, Mexico
$arr1 = array("Toronto", "Ottawa", "Montreal", "Quebec");
$arr2 = array("Boston", "New York", "Santa Barbara", "San Francisco");
$arr3 = array("Mexico City", "Cozumel", "Cancun", "Aculpoco");
# array 4 is an associative array
$arr4 = array("Canada" => $arr1, "USA" => $arr2, "Mexico" => $arr3);
print_r($arr4);
?>
```

The tutorial video says I'll just need to follow the instructions/code and perform "php array1.php" but getting this:

```
$ php array1.php
<?
# Canada, USA, Mexico
$arr1 = array("Toronto", "Ottawa", "Montreal", "Quebec");
$arr2 = array("Boston", "New York", "Santa Barbara", "San Francisco");
$arr3 = array("Mexico City", "Cozumel", "Cancun", "Aculpoco");
# array 4 is an associative array
$arr4 = array("Canada" => $arr1, "USA" => $arr2, "Mexico" => $arr3);
print_r($arr4);
?>
```

Comment: Change the open tag "<?php"

Comment: always use <?php, its much nicer and simpler to read at first glance :)

Comment: When you say you use the command line.. What exactly do you mean?

Comment: What's the error you're getting?

Comment: You better check how old this tutorial video is...

Comment: @circusdei it worked out withthe the tag "<?php" :-) 

the tutorial video is a classic php tutorial by Dean Davis, might be around 2006 video I guess

Answer (score 0):

with the help of @circusdei.. Thanks

```
$ php array1.php
Array
(
    [Canada] => Array
        (
           [0] => Toronto
           [1] => Ottawa
           [2] => Montreal
           [3] => Quebec
        )

    [USA] => Array
       (
          [0] => Boston
          [1] => New York
          [2] => Santa Barbara
          [3] => San Francisco
       )

    [Mexico] => Array
      (
         [0] => Mexico City
         [1] => Cozumel
         [2] => Cancun
         [3] => Aculpoco
      )

    )
```